# There is an exception which quits the application in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile, twilio, mobile-development, twilio-programmable-chat

I used twilio_chat_conversation: ^1.0.4 in flutter. A problem occured and that quits the application on the emulator and on the device. You can look the error logs. Here are they:

```
D/EGL_emulation(22134): app_time_stats: avg=4983.07ms min=2.97ms max=168872.84ms count=34
I/System.out(22134): call.method->initializeConversationClient
I/ConversationsClientImpl(22134): Twilio Conversations SDK version 6.0.0-d66e9451c
D/EGL_emulation(22134): app_time_stats: avg=129.09ms min=3.01ms max=615.55ms count=9
D/TrafficStats(22134): tagSocket(214) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
W/System.err(22134): SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
W/System.err(22134): SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
W/System.err(22134): SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
W/tomer_app.debug(22134): Reducing the number of considered missed Gc histogram windows from 106 to 100
I/System.out(22134): onClientSynchronization synchronizationStatus->1call.method->joinConversation
I/System.out(22134): call.method->subscribeToMessageUpdate
I/System.out(22134): conversation onSynchronizationChanged->IDENTIFIER
I/System.out(22134): call.method->getMessages
D/AndroidRuntime(22134): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(22134): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(22134): Process: com.airporttransfer.customer_app.debug, PID: 22134
E/AndroidRuntime(22134): com.twilio.conversations.ListenerException: Exception thrown by a listener. Your application might have a problem in listener implementation. Listeners must never throw uncaught exceptions. See 'Caused by:' below for more details.
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at com.twilio.conversations.internal.RethrowingForwarder$RethrowingProxy.invoke(RethrowingForwarder.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at $Proxy2.onSuccess(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at com.twilio.conversations.internal.CallbackListenerForwarder$1.run(CallbackListenerForwarder.java:34)
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
E/AndroidRuntime(22134): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Messages are not available at the moment. Synchronize the conversation first.
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at com.twilio.conversations.ConversationImpl.getMessages(ConversationImpl.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at com.twilio.conversations.ConversationImpl.getLastMessages(ConversationImpl.java:280)
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at com.example.twilio_chat_conversation.Conversation.ConversationHandler$8.onSuccess(ConversationHandler.java:286)
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at com.example.twilio_chat_conversation.Conversation.ConversationHandler$8.onSuccess(ConversationHandler.java:283)
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    at com.twilio.conversations.internal.RethrowingForwarder$RethrowingProxy.invoke(RethrowingForwarder.java:121)
E/AndroidRuntime(22134):    ... 11 more
D/EGL_emulation(22134): app_time_stats: avg=2058.11ms min=2058.11ms max=2058.11ms count=1
I/Process (22134): Sending signal. PID: 22134 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
```

I tried many solutions on the Internet which are in github, stackoverflow and ai.

Comment: `E/AndroidRuntime(22134): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Messages are not available at the moment. Synchronize the conversation first.` This is your issue!

Comment: I know that issue but I used in a different page and that works, but in this page i faced with this issue. There are not to much differences between pages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.